Why is my ObjectCaptureSession crashing when I call proceedToNextScanPass()?
I am attempting to build an app that uses the ObjectCapture API, but I can't get past this bug. The app crashes 9/10 times when I call proceedToNextScanPass(), if you could please suggest some possible solutions it would be appreciated.
I'm following the Apple Developer Sample Project pretty much down to a tee so I'm not sure what's going wrong. There's also no way to throw an error when using proceedToNextScanPass() so it's difficult to debug.
Here is my AppDataModel, like in the sample project.
@MainActor
@Observable
class AppDataModel: ObservableObject {
    static let instance = AppDataModel()

    enum ModelState {
        case notSet
        case ready
        case capturing
        case prepareToReconstruct
        case reconstructing
        case viewing
        case completed
        case failed
    }

    var state: ModelState = .notSet {
        didSet {
            performStateTransition(from: oldValue, to: state)
        }
    }
    var captureFolderManager: CaptureFolderManager?
    var objectCaptureSession: ObjectCaptureSession?
    var photogrammetrySession: PhotogrammetrySession?

    var orbit: Int = 0

    private init() {
        state = .ready
    }

    func endCapture() {
        state = .completed
    }

    func removeCaptureFolder() {
        guard let url = captureFolderManager?.captureFolder else { return }
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url)
    }

    private func performStateTransition(from fromState: ModelState, to toState: ModelState) {
        if fromState == toState { return }

        switch toState {
        case .ready:
            do {
                try startNewCapture()
            } catch {
                print("Starting new capture failed!")
            }
        case .prepareToReconstruct:
            objectCaptureSession = nil
            do {
                try startReconstruction()
            } catch {
                print("Reconstruction failed!")
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    private func startReconstruction() throws {
        var configuration = PhotogrammetrySession.Configuration()

        guard let captureFolderManager else {
            preconditionFailure("CaptureFolderManager unexpectedly nil!")
        }

        configuration.checkpointDirectory = captureFolderManager.checkpointFolder
        photogrammetrySession = try PhotogrammetrySession(
            input: captureFolderManager.imagesFolder,
            configuration: configuration
        )

        state = .reconstructing
    }
}

extension AppDataModel {
    private func startNewCapture() throws {
        captureFolderManager = try CaptureFolderManager()
        objectCaptureSession = ObjectCaptureSession()

        guard let captureFolderManager, let session = objectCaptureSession else {
            throw NSError(domain: "AppDataModel", code: 1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to initialize session or folder manager"])
        }

        var configuration = ObjectCaptureSession.Configuration()
        configuration.isOverCaptureEnabled = true
        configuration.checkpointDirectory = captureFolderManager.checkpointFolder
        session.start(imagesDirectory: captureFolderManager.imagesFolder, configuration: configuration)

        state = .capturing
    }

    private func reset() {
        objectCaptureSession = nil
        captureFolderManager = nil
        state = .ready
    }
}

As well as the main view where I'm making the call to next scan pass
struct CapturePrimaryView: View {
    @Environment(AppDataModel.self) var appModel
    var session: ObjectCaptureSession
    @State private var currentOrbit = 1

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if session.userCompletedScanPass {
                if currentOrbit <= 2 {
                    Button("Continue") {
                        proceedToNextScanPass()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                    .tint(.yellow)
                } else if currentOrbit == 3 {
                    Button("Finish") {
                        completeCapture()
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
                }
            } else {
                ObjectCaptureView(session: session, cameraFeedOverlay: { GradientBackground() })
                    .hideObjectReticle(false)
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        }
        .onChange(of: session.state) { _, newValue in
            print("Session State Changed: \(newValue)")
        }
        .id(session.id)
    }

    private func proceedToNextScanPass() {
        guard session.state == .capturing else {
            print("Error: Cannot begin a new scan pass because the session is not in capturing state. Current state: \(session.state)")
            return
        }

        session.beginNewScanPass()
        currentOrbit += 1
        print("New scan pass started successfully. Current orbit: \(currentOrbit)")
    }

    private func completeCapture() {
        appModel.state = .completed
    }
}

And my main ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(AppDataModel.self) var appModel
    @State private var hasDetectionFailed = false
    @State private var showReconstructionView = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if appModel.state == .capturing {
                if let session = appModel.objectCaptureSession {
                    CapturePrimaryView(session: session)
                        .overlay {
                            Spacer()
                            
                            CaptureButton(session: session, hasDetectionFailed: $hasDetectionFailed)
                        }
                }
            } else {
                Text("Blank")
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        })
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
        })
        .sheet(isPresented: $showReconstructionView) {
            if let _ = appModel.captureFolderManager {
                Text("Reconstruct")
            }
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
private struct CaptureButton: View {
    @Environment(AppDataModel.self) var appModel
    var session: ObjectCaptureSession
    @Binding var hasDetectionFailed: Bool
    @State private var show = true
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if show {
                Button("Continue") {
                    performAction()
                }
                .bold()
                .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func performAction() {
        if session.state == .ready {
            hasDetectionFailed = !(session.startDetecting())
        } else if case .detecting = session.state {
            session.startCapturing()
            show = false
        }
    }
}


do not mix @Observable and ObservableObject like you do in
@Observable class AppDataModel: ObservableObject.... I recommend using  @Observable. Use one source of truth for your data model and pass it to other views as described in the docs, rather than using a singleton. See Managing data

@workingdogsupportUkraine Didn't even notice I had ObservableObject there, thank you! I removed it though, as well as the singleton, adjusted the data flow, and it's still crashing when I call proceedToNextScanPass()
